# How to tree shake unused constants in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one .ts file corresponding to **every** component containing thousands of exported constants but in my application I only use a couple dozen of them in every component. Is there a way to exclude the unused constants from the built bundle **without** needing to import the constants that I need **one by one** to each component?

I have tried different scenarios:

1. import * as constants from 'constants' - I prefer this way to include my constants but if I use them in my template all of the constants get to the bundle
2. import { X } from 'constants' - This way only the imported constants are included in the bundle but I dont want to import dozens of constants one by one
3. dependency injection - Same situation as 1.
4. Putting all the constants into one object then importing the object - Again all the constants get to the budle.
5. import * as constants from 'constants' and creating a variable for every constant I want to use in my template - This way only the imported constants are included in the bundle but I dont want to create dozens of variables in my component for each constants that I need in my template.

Note: Deleting the not needed constants from the .ts file is not an option.

Comment: `I have one .ts file corresponding to every component containing thousands of exported constants` thats' your mistake right there ... but seriously, option 2 is the only solution to this, and most IDE's can help with the import process. you can't tree shake this because you told TS to import ALL of the constants in option 1 and then used that import. paying for the sins of the past at this point.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I dont have a choice but to work with these huge files since they are generated. Thank you so much for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Split that one file into multiple component-based constants

Comment: Every component has its own big file of constants. It is not one big file for the whole application, it is one for each component unfortunatelly.